# Is there a python variable expansion for zsh

Tags: string, shell, zsh, padding

Can someone tell me the **zsh way** to pad strings to a fixed width like python variable expansion ? After searched a lot, I find this funcionality present in [fish-shell](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/string-pad.html), anyone knows how to simulate this command? Thanks.

Example:

[image]

Comment: It's not obvious what Python feature or syntax you are thinking of.

Comment: I would like to write a message X to a certain length fixed and centralize the message, like print(f'{'Some text':^-30}') in python

Answer (score 0):

`zsh` has built in padding support, see `man zshexpn` (search for padding).

Example with left padding:

```
$ strs=(one two)
$ for s in ${strs[@]}; do echo ${(l:40:)s}; done                                                                                           
                                one
                                two
```

pad with a character:

```
$ for s in ${strs[@]}; do echo ${(l:40::.:)s}; done                                                                                        
.....................................one
.....................................two
```

And right padding:

```
$ for s in ${strs[@]}; do echo ${(r:40::.:)s}; done                                                                                   
one.....................................
two.....................................
```

And combined:

```
$ strs=("three" "four")                                                                                                                        
$ for s in ${strs[@]}; do echo ${(r:20::.:l:20::.:)s}; done                                                                                
..................three.................
..................four..................
```

To complete the example set: Pad with dots, but add spaces around the elements:

```
$ for s in ${strs[@]}; do echo ${(r:20::.:: :l:20::.:: :)s}; done                                  
................. three ................
................. four .................
```

And another example: If you don't need/want to use a variable, use the default-value notation `:-TEXT`:

```
$ echo ${(r:20::.:: :l:20::.:: :):-Text}
................. Text ................
```

Comment: Nice utility, can I write a message after use  zshexpn instead call a variable? Like ${(r:20::.:: :l:20::.:: :)'INTERPOLATION'}

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you find a variable-less solution as an additional example.